# Compiler Error in Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting compiler error while running below code:

```
Sub AddNameInList()

  FilmName = InputBox("Type in a new film name")

   Worksheets("sheet2").Activate

   Range("b1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

   ActiveCell.Value = FilmName

   MsgBox FilmName & " was added to the list"

End Sub
```

**Error Message**

> Compiler Error: Variable not defined

Comment: on which line does it break?

Comment: In First Line at "FileName"

Comment: I guess these issues would be clearer if the error message was changed to say "Variable not dimensioned"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare FilmName:

```
Sub AddNameInList()
Dim FilmName As String

FilmName = InputBox("Type in a new film name")

Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = FilmName

MsgBox FilmName & " was added to the list"

End Sub
```

If you have the Option Explicit set either at the top of the module or in the settings then it requires that all variables be declared.

Also avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`.  In general they are not needed and only slow down the code.